# Manipulate LPCWSTR in c

Tags: c, winapi, lpcwstr

I have a given LPCWSTR variable, which holds a full path.

I want to extract from it only the file name.

Any suggestions how can I manipulate the LPCWSTR to achieve that?

In addition - How can I get the char in a specific index of the LPCWSTR?

Thank you.

Comment: `LPCWSTR` is a `typedef` for `wchar_t const *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windows function [PathStripPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773756(v=vs.85).aspx) will do what you want.  Since you have a Unicode string you'll want to call the "W" version PathStripPathW.

Comment: Also see [`PathFindFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773589.aspx). `PathStripPath()` modifies the buffer passed to it. `PathFindFileName()` returns a pointer to the filename within the buffer without modifying the buffer itself.